# MySQL - Access denied when connecting locally but able to connect remotely

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a PHP application hosted both on a server and locally with XAMP, and I've got a DB hosted in that same server, too.

When trying to establish a connection with my DB I instance a new mysqli object like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, MY_DB);
```

The value for those constants are the same for my local and remote applications but for some reason they work only when used on XAMP; I get 'Access denied for user' when trying to connect from the server and I have no idea what the problem might be.

Sorry for my bad english, and thanks for the help :)

Comment: Does your user have access to connect to the server remotely? Often users like root are restricted to local access only, and another user(restricted) user must be used for remote connections.

Comment: I can connect to the server remotely with no problems from the application hosted with XAMP (since the DB is hosted in the remote server), but when trying to connect from the remote server to the DB in that very same server I get the acces denied error.

Comment: are you sure ? user name and password is same ?

Comment: Yeah, I basically copied and pasted the definition of those constants from one place to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two options: Either you are binding to the remote IP and not the local one or you messed up the permissions.

**1. Binding the IP adress**

If you followed an online tutorial on how to allow remote access, you probably set the config option `bind-adress` to you axternal IP. This means, your server will bind only externally but not on the internal loopback (`127.0.0.1`/`localhost`).

All you have to do is:

1. Open your config file (usually `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) with root permissions
2. Locate the setting `bind-adress` and set it to `0.0.0.0`

---

**2. Permissions**

Try granting the permission through the terminal to `'<your user>'@'%'`.
If you don't understand what this means, read the `GRANT` manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html).

Here's an example for giving superuser permissions to a user from anywhere for every database:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '<your user>'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I wouldn't recommend using the above on a production server since it is a big security risk.

Comment: Thank you franga2000, you are right, it had to do with permissions. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

In this code which you are using

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, MY_DB);
```

i think while executing in localhost (xampp) you replacing 'HOST' with your 'Domain name' or 'IP address' but

When you are trying at server where the application and database are on same server you need to put 'HOST' as 'localhost'

try to replace 'HOST' with 'localhost' it will work.

Comment: HOST, USER etc.. are constants, you don't know whats in there so this answer is totally wrong. 127.0.0.1 can stay on both servers, depending on the configuration. The problem is that he obviously did **not** create a user with the right privileges.